# How to make some objects/data global across files and functions in python pycharm project?

Tags: python

I have created a project in python where I have sets of functions in different files. I have some static data which is being used by these functions. How can I make the data available to all files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have made the English more standard and concise. I also removed the pycharm tag, as it's not important to the question. This is a good question.

Comment: Could you please provide more details regarding your issue? Maybe explain what kind of data specifically would you like to make available globally? What is the structure of your project?

That would help with providing an answer.